# Disable tab autocompletion in PHP interactive mode

Tags: php, readline

I have `set disable-completion on` in my `~/.inputrc`, however this doesn't affect php in interactive mode (`php -a`).

I would like to copy some code from another editor to the php interactive shell which uses tab characters as indention.

Answer (score 0):

I searched PHP source for this 2 years ago. Could not find a simple way
to do this. Assume it is impossible.

You should convert the tabbed code to spaces and then copy.